# but titles on variants | shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

```
   {% for option in product.options_with_values %}          
   <select  class="option-selector {{option.name}}" data-var="{{forloop.index}}">             
   {% if product.available %}              
            {% for values in option.values %}
         <option value="{{values}}">{{values}}</option>
      {% endfor %}              
   {% endif %}             
   </select>            
    {% endfor %}
```

this is the code i want to put titles before the swatches options like
size  color

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, you can you the same like this:

```
{% for product_option in product.options_with_values %}
  <label>
    {{ product_option.name }}
    <select>
      {% for value in product_option.values %}
        <option {% if product_option.selected_value == value %}selected{% endif %}>
          {{ value }}
        </option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </label>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]
[image]
Documentation [Link](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product#product-options_with_values)